# creating discrete ranges with custom classes

Tags: ruby

Since a range is the values between two endpoints, we need to compare the values between the two endpoints and therefore we use the comparison operator <=>, which compares its two operands and evaluates to –1, 0, or 1, depending on their relative order.

Second, if we desire iteration, then we must have a discrete set of range members, not a continuous set. We use succ to create discrete ranges. Integers are for sure discrete.

So I build this class called Apple. As you can see, I define both the comparison operator method <=> and the succ method, because I want a discrete range:

```
class Apple
 attr_accessor :val

 def initialize(val)
  @val = val
 end

  def <=>(other)
    if @val > other.val
      1
    elsif @val == other.val
      0
    else
      -1
    end
  end

  def succ
    val.succ
  end
end
```

Now I create three apples and I want to get a range of all apples inclusive:

```
 a = Apple.new 1
 => #<Apple:0x00000001d3fa30 @val=1> 
 b = Apple.new 2
 => #<Apple:0x00000001d35210 @val=2> 
 c = Apple.new 3
 => #<Apple:0x00000001d2fbf8 @val=3> 
 (a..b).to_a
 => [#<Apple:0x00000001d3fa30 @val=2>]
```

Hm, something unexpected happened. I was expecting the array to include all three apples inclusive. However, it only returned the middle apple. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the line `elsif @val = other.val` is intended?

Comment: If you want `Apple#<=>` to reflect the `<=>` of `@val` and `other.val`, then do it straightforward. `def <=>(other); @val <=> other.val end`.

Comment: Please remove the IRB prompts and format the code correctly. @sawa, nice concise answer (your first comment).

Comment: @sawa no that was a typo. I meant == not assignment =.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your method's comparison in `elsif` should be with `==`(double equals) not `=`:

```
def <=>(other)
  if @val > other.val
    1
  elsif @val == other.val
    0
  else
    -1
  end
end
```

However, you don't have to write all that comparison by yourself, instead you can compare `@val` with `<=>` like this:

```
def <=>(other)
  @val <=> other.val
end
```

Second, `succ` method should return an object of the same class, and you seem to be returning an integer/string(`val.succ` where `val` is integer/string respectively) instead of an object of the `Apple` class. So it should be:

```
def succ
  Apple.new(@val + 1) # or Apple.new(@val.succ)
end
```

After making these changes code seems to work:

```
class Apple
  attr_accessor :val

  def initialize(val)
    @val = val
  end

  def <=>(other)
    @val <=> other.val
  end

  def succ
    Apple.new(@val + 1)
  end
end

a = Apple.new 1
b = Apple.new 2
c = Apple.new 3
puts (a..b).to_a
#=> [#<Apple:0x007fa10a97bc08 @val=1>, #<Apple:0x007fa10a97bb18 @val=2>]
puts (a..c).to_a
#=> [#<Apple:0x007fc8d3957b28 @val=1>, #<Apple:0x007fc8d3957858 @val=2>, #<Apple:0x007fc8d3957830 @val=3>]
```

Comment: I suggest you delete the last block of code and end with `After making these changes it seems to work fine`. It really doesn't add anything.

Comment: Example of `"After making these changes code seems to work"` might give an idea that's how output would look like. All done in good spirit. :)